# I This i called the function on the Onsubmit event of form but when my jquery function return true still its not going to action page

Tags: php

In this programme i want to submit my form data if state name is already not present in database.if it is present in database then it gives mi alert that name already present and form not submited. but in the following programme if name is already present then then it gives alert message and form also not submitted. but if state name is not present then still it is not submitted my values(it is not calling form action="add_state_process.php"). i think i am wrong in returning true and false in javascript function.plz tell mi where i am wrong

```
     <form name="addcategoryfrm" id="addcategoryfrm" onsubmit="return check_state();" action="add_state_process.php"    method="POST">


        <div class="formrow" style="margin-top:0px;height:80px;width:100%; padding-left:30%;">
                <div class="txttitle" >Country Name</div>   
                <div class="txtinputouter1"  style="padding-left:8px;">
                <select name="country" id="country"  class="required txtinput" value="">
                  <option value="">--- Select Country --- </option>
                <?php
                include("../config/database.php");
                $query="SELECT * FROM `country`";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                    echo    $query;
                    //$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    $row1=mysql_num_rows($result);
                    echo $row1;
                    while($numrow=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    { ?>

                    <option value=" <?php echo $numrow['id']; ?> ">
                     <?php echo $numrow['name']; ?>
                     </option>

                    <?php } ?>



                </select>

            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="formrow" style="margin-top:0px;height:80px;width:100%; padding-left:30%;">
                <div class="txttitle">State Name </div> 
                <div class="txtinputouter1" style="padding-left:1%;">
                <input type="text" class="required txtinput" name="state" id="state" class="categoryname" onblur=";"/>
                </div>
                </div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1" style="padding-left:43%;padding-top:10px;">
                <input type="submit"  class="subbutton" value="Submit"/>

                </div>
        <div id="demo"></div>
            </form>




////function call

    <script> 
 function check_state()
     {
         valid=false;
    var txtarea12 = document.getElementById("country").value;
     var name = document.getElementById("state").value;
     //var valid=true;
     //alert(name);
     //alert(txtarea12);
     //$name = name; 
     $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
     url: 'ajax-state-model.php', 
     data: { name: name,

    countryid:txtarea12
     }, 
     success: function(result) 
     { 
     if (result == 1) 
     { 

     alert("state name already present"); 
       var txtarea = document.getElementById("state");

         txtarea.value="";
        txtarea.focus();
    valid=false;

     }
     else
     {
         valid=true;
     }

     }, 
     error: function(err) 
     { alert(err); } 
     });

    return valid;

     }
     </script> 



///function ajax call

<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username1']))
{
    include("../config/database.php");
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $countryid=$_GET['countryid'];


    $query="select * from  state where country_name=$countryid && state_name='$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    //echo $query;
    $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($rows>0)
    {
        echo 1;

    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning! Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks!

Comment: try specify data type in your ajax call. You return html data so for response in ajax would be dataType: 'html', the best is use json type

Comment: then you try if(result == "1")

Comment: i change the datatype to json but now in this case if variable valid  true or false  still it goes to form action page